# Flutter / Dart - Parsing a Textfield controller text for multiple matches of a RegExp's and calling a function each time it matches

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a textfield controller which matches a RegExp whenever the user type it in. For example the typed in string may be `"@jack and @jill went up the hill"`. The following code will match the taghandles and list them.

Firstly the TextField:

```
TextField(
  controller: myController,
)
```

Which listens for each input into the text field and passes it to a function:

```
myController.addListener(_matchTextToRegexp);
```

The function then matches taghandles ie. '@jack' '@jill'

```
_matchTextToRegexp() {
  String value = myController.text;
  RegExp regExpTaghandle = RegExp(r"\B@+([\w]+)\b");
  Iterable matches = regExpTaghandle.allMatches(value);
  matches.forEach((match) {
    tagHandle = value.substring(match.start, match.end);
    _callToAction(tagHandle);
  }
}
```

The issue is that i want to call a function `_callToAction()` and pass it the taghandle (for example it could pass the substring/taghandle to a typeahead suggestion dropdown menu as the user types it in - similar functionality to a tweet mention). This code works for one taghandle, but if the users continues inputting text (or adds multiple taghandles) into the form it will keep matching the first taghandle even though the user has typed passed the first taghandle.

So how do you distinguish between multiple taghandles as they are dynamically typed in?

Comment: we can maintain a `List` of previously entered `tagHandles` and check in this `List` as user keeps on typing. Like for example 
`List<String> addedTags = [];
_callToAction({String tagHandle}){
  if(!addedTags.contains(tagHandle)){
    addedTags.add(tagHandle);
    print('Currently on $tagHandle');
  }else{
    print('added previously $tagHandle');
  }
  
}`